# Keyword Not Recognized error in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, sql

I have a query that I've been trying to execute on `phpMyAdmin`, the query is as follows:

```
UPDATE `energyconsumption` SET `Date`= CURRENT_DATE, WHERE USER = '17';
```

This is response that I get back:

2 errors were found during analysis.

> Unrecognized keyword. (near "CURRENT_DATE" at position 39)
>
> Unexpected token. (near "," at position 51)

How do I resolve this error? And how do I use `CURRENT_DATE` in the correct way?

**Note:**

I've searched online about the correct way of using the function `CURRENT_DATE`, but I haven't had much luck on find a good site that explains it. Also, *w3schools* website has been down since yesterday so I haven't had the chance to look there on the correct syntax for using this function.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use now() instead of CURRENT_DATE and remove the ,

Comment: @ Gemelo Molinero Thank you bro! Appreciate the speedy response

Comment: No problem, make a +1 if the answer works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems with your syntax, have you tried this? Also instead of CURRENT_DATE use CURDATE() and remove the comma before WHERE.

```
UPDATE energyconsumption SET Date= CURDATE() WHERE USER = '17';
```

**UPDATE:**

CURDATE() returns the date part or NOW() returns the date and timestamp. Depends on the data type you have defined on your table design.

Comment: Cheers! I'll look into using CURDATE()

Answer (score 0):

Its ok. I've just resolved the problem. This is the query I've executed:

UPDATE energyconsumption SET Date= CURRENT_DATE**,** WHERE USER = '17';

The comma was giving me the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ',' from the query

```
UPDATE `energyconsumption` SET `Date`= CURRENT_DATE WHERE USER = '17';
```